# how to handle left and right scrolling in pivot control for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot, gesture, photo-gallery

I want apply scrolling in my application like photo app hub in windows phone. When last photo come at that time left scrolling is stop and first photo come than right scrolling stop.

How can i do with pivot control?

Any Idea?